# iphone json web-services post data

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I am working on one iOS Application, in which i need to post the json web-data to web-service url & base of that i need to get response from server side.

as i have tried to code to send the web-data with json formate but unfortunately yet i haven't got any help to make that possible.

below is the web-url & json request data which i need to pass on web-services to get response,

WebUrl : http://testing.com/controllogic/webservices/all_data_webservice/set_device_token_ios

web data pass : `webdata={"device_token":"test"}`

now i am confused how i can pass `webdata={"device_token":"test"}` json post to get response from server side.

below is my code which i have tired to make that possible,

### Coding:

```
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://testing.com/controllogic/webservices/all_data_webservice/set_device_token_ios"];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Akash IOS PUSH", @"device_token",
                              nil];

   // NSString *string_val = @"webdata=";

   // NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsData                                                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   // NSString *myString_VAL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",string_val,jsonDict];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: postURL
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval: 60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
    [request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];

    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                       queue: queue
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (error || !data) {
                                   // Handle the error

                                   NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                               } else {
                                   // Handle the success

                                   NSLog(@"Server Responce :%@",response);
                               }
                           }
     ];
```

---

Please any body help me to make this possible.

Comment: Hello Yu Hao, thanks for edit, could you please help me for my this query, as i need to get support to solve this issue..

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code.I hope this may work.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Akash IOS      PUSH", @"device_token",nil];


NSData * JsonData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString * jsonString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testing.com/controllogic/webservices/all_data_webservice/set_device_token_ios"]]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error || !data) {
                               // Handle the error

                               NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                           } else {
                               // Handle the success

                               NSLog(@"Server Response :%@",response);
                           }
                       }
 ];
```

Comment: Hey Raj, i have tried your given code , but sorry to say its not getting success response. but once i tested this web-services on advance rest client its given sucess responce.

Comment: here is the request on advance rest client,

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.48 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Hi client side coding is Ok may be the problem is at the backend,Because I have used above code many times and it works perfectly...:)Can you please provide me response code or error that you are getting..

Comment: okay shall we discuss via chat by creating room at stack overflow ? so that i can send you more details!

Comment: how i can send request to make chat with stackoverlow chat room ?

Comment: could you please join on this group : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37174/d-iphone-developer-group , so that we can discuss more.